# On examples of action of C-star simple group on von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can there exist a faithful action of a $C^{*}$-simple group $G$ on a von Neumann algebra $(M,\varphi)$ equipped with faithful normal state $\varphi$  such that action preserves the state $\varphi$ and the identity automorphism can be approximated by non-identity automorphisms i.e, there exists $g_{n}$ $\in$ $G$, such that 
\begin{align*}
\|\alpha_{g_{n}}(x)-x\|_{2}\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
as $n\rightarrow \infty$ $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $M$ and $\alpha_{g_{n}}\neq I$, $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ is the GNS Hilbert space $L^{2}(M,\varphi)$ norm?

Comment: Some questions which might improve the question: what is a $C^*$-simple group?  What is $\|\cdot\|_2$ (asked because you have placed no restriction on your von Neumann algebra $M$).

Comment: A group is said to be $C^*$-simple if its reduced $C^*$-algebra is simple (every proper quotient is reduced to $\{0\}$). This also means that whenever a nonzero unitary representation is weakly contained in the regular representation, then it weakly contains the regular representation.

Comment: It's obviously possible for $G=F_\infty$. Also, e.g., if $G$ embeds densely into a compact group $K$, then $G\curvearrowright L^\infty(K)$ is an example.

Comment: @Ozawa Sir, can you please elaborate the reason why this example will work?